# VS code always opening 4x split screen window when opened?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to set the VS code window so when it open for the first time, it does not open up 4x split window of the same file?

Answer (score 1):

Click on `View > Editor Layout > Single` and restart vscode to check if it opens in single layout mode.

Comment: There is no toolbar to click on View on the VS code on WIndows 10?

Comment: You might be in Full Screen Mode. Press F11 to go to the normal mode and you should see the toolbar.